# Prevent special characters in WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have got following C# code from this link: [How to prevent users from typing special characters in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018299/how-to-prevent-users-from-typing-special-characters-in-textbox)

```
  string allowedchar = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  if (!TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(allowedchar.Contains))
  {
   // Not allowed char detected
  }
```

Following code is vb.net version of above code

```
    Dim allowedchar As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    If Not TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(allowedchar.Contains) Then
        ' Not allowed char detected
    End If
```

How can I solve this error? : https://prnt.sc/mzsmkd

Error message:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Contains' accepts
>   this number of arguments

Comment: `string.Contains` is a method not a property. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-string-contains-method/

Comment: You can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/463335/6299857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a LINQ solution, I'd use:

```
Dim allowedchar As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
If Not TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(function(x) allowedchar.contains(x)) Then
    ' Not allowed char detected
End If
```

`String.Contains` expects a parameter which is what it will search for. `.All` loops through each letter in `TXT_NewPassword.Text` & `function(x)` allows you to access that letter through `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. But why do you think following linked C# code is accepted as solved answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018299/how-to-prevent-users-from-typing-special-characters-in-textbox

Comment: @Markowitz Honestly, I'm not sure. I would have expected to have seen the C# code as `TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(x=>allowedchar.Contains(x))`.

Comment: The answer is that it is completely valid syntax in C#. There is a long but step-by-step explanation of why it's valid here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422304/5198140

Comment: @Markowitz, the translation to VB should have been `If Not TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(AddressOf allowedchar.Contains) Then`.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you. Your code also works. Which one is better your code or ItsPete's code?

Comment: @Markowitz, my previous translation, while closer to the original C# code, is in error and should have been `If Not TXT_NewPassword.Text.All(AddressOf DirectCast(allowedchar, IEnumerable(Of Char)).Contains) Then`.  The `String.Contains` method takes a `String` argument.  My previous translation and the one in this answer work because VB does an implicit conversion of a `Char` to a `String` .  C# does not allow this implicit conversion and as such resolves to the `IEnumerable(Of Char).Contains` method that is implemented by the `String` type.